# Reversing an ArrayList of Integers with the aid of a stack

Tags: java, string, list, arraylist, java-8

So I have managed to implement reversing an ArrayList (of Strings) with the aid of a stack, but I cannot figure out how to do it with integers. I get a stack empty error, any ideas? [Java]

Here is the code:

```
package Class;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Class 
{
    static ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
    static Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack();

    public static ArrayList<Integer> reverseList(ArrayList<Integer> n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
        {
            stack.push(n.get(i));
            n.remove(0);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i != stack.size();)
        {
            n.add(stack.pop());
        }
        return n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        list.add(1);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(4);
        list.add(5);

        System.out.println(list);
        ArrayList n = reverseList(list);
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

Error is empty stack error.

Comment: Reversing a list of integers should not be different from reversing a list of strings. So if you've managed to do the latter then this should already be it (hint: replace `String` with a generic type). If that doesn't work then please show us what you've done for strings.

Comment: This is the exact same code but I have changed the data type String to Integer - it does not work. Please don't be patronising!

Comment: Can we see the whole log?

Comment: I'm not patronising at least not intentionally :) However, as I said, if you've got it to work for strings then the _exact_ same code (just with `Integer` instead of `String`) should work as well. If it doesn't there would be 2 possibilities: 1) the code isn't the same or 2) the string version didn't work as well or at least not as intended.

Comment: The code is the same and it worked just fine? so then there is another posibility... and also, this is the whole log

Comment: With "whole log" I'd say Adrien was refering to "I get a stack empty error" - if you get an exception or error we'd need to see the entire stacktrace (ideally with the indicated lines marked in your post so that we don't have to count lines or guess).

Comment: Here's a few side notes: 1) `for(int i = 0; i != stack.size();)` could be simplified to `while(stack.size() != 0)` or `while( !stack.empty() )`.  2) The stack doesn't have to be static, in fact that could cause bugs. Since you only need it inside `reverseList(...)` you should make it a local variable (declared in the method) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Without reinventing the wheel, can't you just use:

```
Collections.reverse(list);
```

When it comes to question, here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
{
    stack.push(n.get(i));
    n.remove(0);
}
```

You are always removing the first element, but getting some in the middle afterwards, this leads to loosing some elements. You should use an `Iterator` for this. Check out the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/Iterator.html) for detailed description.

Comment: Thanks, I know the collection function exists - but I am trying to use a stack - It's a project. So how do I change this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
{
    stack.push(n.get(i));
    n.remove(0);
}
```

do this

```
for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
{
    stack.push(n.get(i));
}
n.clear();
```

and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

As already has been pointed out, one major problem is this part:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n.size(); i++)
{
  stack.push(n.get(i));
  n.remove(0);
}
```

Here you always remove the first element from the list but get the element at index `i` to add it to the stack.

Let's analyse that by taking your list of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5:

- Step 1: `i = 0` so you push 1 and remove 1 from the list which now becomes 2, 3, 4, 5
- Step 2: `i = 1` so you push 3 and remove 2, so the list now is 3, 4, 5
- Step 3: `i = 2` so you push 5 and remove 3. The list now is 4, 5 and has a length smaller than `i` so the loop stops.

The problem: you're not adjusting `i` to accomodate for the removal.

As m.k suggested you could add all elements to the stack and after that remove all.

Alternatively use an iterator:

```
for( Iterator<Integer> itr = n.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
  stack.push(itr.next()); //this advances the iterator so only call next() once per iteration
  itr.remove(); //this removes the element from the list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> reverseList(ArrayList<Integer> n) {
    for(int i = n.size()-1; i >=0; i--) {
        stack.push(n.get(i));
    }
    n.clear();
    while (stack.size() !=0)
        n.add(stack.pop());
    return n;
}
```

there's many ways to reverse things, but seems like it is important for you to use stack, so change your method a bit with above code